# how does compiler allocate memory to a program?

Tags: c, memory-management, compiler-construction

Suppose I am writing a program in C like:

```
Code: [1 global var, main(with local vars), 3 functions(with local vars)]
```

Given that function calls will be made on a stack frame, how does the compiler know at one glance how much memory to allocate?

Does it ever happen that the compiler went wrong and the program got out-of-memory error? Or will the compiler always allocate exact or extra memory?

Does it mediate with the OS on this? Or does it take its own decisions? Does the OS intervene anyway?

**Edit:** I found an answer which helps a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102036/5324086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The global variable ends up in `.data` or `.bss`.
- main and the functions end up in program memory, typically called `.text`.
- Calculating stack usage is never the compiler's responsibility. All it does is to create functions which push/pop variables onto the stack, but it doesn't calculate some worst-case scenario for you. The compiler may however strive to minimize stack usage, by using CPU registers or function inlining to optimize the code.

> Given that function calls will be made on a stack frame, how does the compiler know at one glance how much memory to allocate?

It doesn't know. Stack allocations are done in runtime and it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the program doesn't run out of stack memory.

> Does it ever happen that the compiler went wrong and the program got out-of-memory error? Or will the compiler always allocate exact or extra memory?

All the compiler allocates in your example is memory for the global variable, which ends up in data/bss segment and not on the stack. The compiler/linker knows how much RAM it can use for data/bss and will hopefully tell you when you run out of that memory.

Comment: If the programmer is forced to write some program which will take up huge resources, won't the compiler optimize something if it senses that a stackoverflow will occur?

Comment: @Spandan It doesn't keep track of the stack so it can't tell. In for example desktop programming, it is the programmer's responsibility to allocate huge objects on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: "Calculating stack usage is never the compiler's responsibility". Incorrect, compilers do keep track of stack used by actual arguments (during compilation). When the caller cleans up the stack (eg C) it doesn't pop, just adds the number of bytes to SP. In fact, the stack can not grow or shrink without the compiler's involvement. The only way to change stack space is (1:grow) calling a function and passing arguments to it (2:grow) declaring locals in a function (3:shrink) return from a function. In a language without recursion a compiler could tell you the max stack usage precisely.

Comment: @user1666959 Keeping track of the stack pointer is not the same thing as keeping track of the total stack size. The compiler _could_ tell you the stack usage by calculating it statically (some do), but it is not _obliged_ to do so. Feel free to compile & run the program `int main(void){ int x [10000000000000000]; }` on GCC.

Comment: @user1666959 Also "the stack can not grow or shrink without the compiler's involvement" is nonsense on most systems. On embedded systems you have hardware interrupts. On desktop systems you have threads and callback functions.

Comment: It's fairly simple to add a function call to the prologue to do a simple stack check (e.g. by compiling with profiling but link an own _mcount) to debug excessive stack usage or unexpected recursion

Comment: @Lundin I'm a bit confused after reading your answer: if it is not compiler's responsibility to track stack usage, then which entity shall request memory for stack? Initially when a process starts, if we look at its virtual memory space, only a few memory pages might be allocated for stack segment. When the program is running, it might run into case where current stack pages are not enough, so someone has to map new pages (e.g. mmap) in order to grow the stack. Not sure who is responsible for this task

Comment: @torez233 It depends on the system, but generally stack size is determined at link time. In case of OS they typically give a fixed maximum size per process and in case of bare metal you specify the stack size itself. When there is not enough stack memory left, you get a stack overflow bug, common enough that someone decided to name this site after it.

Comment: @Lundin if the stack size is known at the link time, when process starts to execute, will all virtual pages of stack segment got mapped to physical page frames at once, or initially only a few pages are mapped and the rest of virtual pages will be mapped on demand? During runtime, will kernel code invoke system call such as mmap to dynamically map page in?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually three memory locations you should be aware of.

The Data segment (and the BSS segment), where the global and static variables reside. The compiler can know at compile time the size of all global and static variables, and tell the loader to allocate the memory when the program start. If there isn't enough memory, the program won't start.

The Heap. Allocations using malloc and similar functions use this segment. If there isn't enough memory, the standard library try to grow it, and if it fails, malloc returns a NULL pointer.

The Stack. When a function is called, the space for local variables and parameters is allocated here, and is deallocated when the function returns. If there isn't enough memory, it grows up to a maximum size (usually configurable). If it can't grow or has reached the maximum, a Stack Overflow exception or signal is thrown (a SIGSEGV on Unix).

EDIT: And of course, program instructions are in other segment (Text) and it's size is also known at compile time, like the Data segment.

Comment: "the standard library tries to grow memory on heap" - can you please elaborate a bit? Will be very helpful.

Comment: In Unix, the library tries to grow the data segment using sbrk and uses the new space for the heap, or allocates pages from the operating system using mmap.