# does the loader modify relocation information on program startup?

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, loader, virtual-memory

I have always believed that resolving absolute addresses is completely the linker's job. That is, after the linker combines all object files into one executable, it will then modify all absolute addresses to reflect the new location inside the executable. But after reading in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102036/3769877) that the loader does not have to place programs text at the address specified by the linker, I got really confused.

Take this code for example

Main.c

```
 void printMe();
int main(){
    printMe();

    return 0;

}
```

Foo.c

```
/* Lots of other functions*/
void printMe(){
     printf("Hello");
}
```

Say that after linking, the code for `main` gets placed at address 0x00000010 and the code for `printMe` gets placed at address 0x00000020. Then when the program is launched, the loader will indeed load main and `printMe` to their virtual addresses as specified by the linker. But if the loader does not load the program in that manner, then won't that break all absolute address references.

Comment: Absolute address references *would* break, if the loader didn't process fixups.  Fixing this is the whole reason that relocation data exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program is normally composed of several modules created by a linker. There is the executable and usually a number of shared libraries. On some systems one executable can load another executable and call it's starting routine as a function.

If all these compiled uses had fixed addresses, it is likely there would be conflicts upon loading. If two linked modules used the same address, the application could not load.

For decades, relocatable code has been the solution to that problem. A module can be loaded anywhere. Some system take this to the next step and randomly place modules in memory for security.

There are some situations where code cannot be purely relocatable.

If you have something like this:

```
static int b, *a = &b ;
```

the initialization depends upon where the model is placed in memory (and where "b" is located). Linkers usually generate information for such constructs so that the loader can fix them up.

Thus, this is not correct:

> I have always believed that resolving absolute addresses is completely the linker's job.

Comment: So does that mean that after linking all static libraries, the addresses generated by the linker are simply ignored?

Comment: No, the linker creates relative addresses.

Comment: So essentially the linker addresses are only used as offsets and the absolute addresses are determined by the loader?

Comment: That's generally it. There are times when absolute addresses are need for operating system work and linkers usually support that with the right assembly language directives.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, it's not the case here.

If it is linked statically, then the address of function is calculated statically by th linker. Because the relative address is know, so a relative function call is issued, and everything will be fine.

If it is linked dynamically, then ld.so comes in and loads the lib. The symbol is resolve either by [Load-time relocation of shared libraries](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/)
 or by [Position Independent Code (PIC) in shared libraries](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/)
 (these 2 articles aren't writen by me).

To simply put,

1. load-time relocation is done by rewriting code to give them the correct address, which disables wirte-protect and share among different processes.
2. PIC is done by adding 2 sections called GOT and PLT, all at a specific address that can be know at link-time. A call to a function in dynamic lib will first call a ...@plt function (E.x. printf@plt) and then it will `jump *GOT[offset]`. At the first call, this will actually be the address of the next instruction, which will call the dynamic loader to load the function. At the second call, this will be the address of the function. As you can see, this cost additional memory and time compared to normal code.