# Why function pointer in the structure causes relocation at program load-time

Tags: c, linux, relocation

I've the following code that I compile and run on Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// can't be static
void do_stuff(void) {
    ;;
}

typedef void (*func)(void);

struct data {
    func ptr;
};

static const struct data d = {
    .ptr = do_stuff
};

int main() {
    d.ptr();
}
```

If I compile it:

```
gcc -O0 -o main main.c
```

then `d` goes to .data.rel.ro segment.

```
objdump -t main | grep ".data.rel.ro"
0000000000003df8 l    d  .data.rel.ro   0000000000000000              .data.rel.ro
0000000000003df8 l     O .data.rel.ro   0000000000000008              d
```

I understand that reason for it is a relocation done by loader and that's because of function pointer in the "data" structure.

What I don't get is - why it is done like that? What is a reason for having relocation here?

Comment: Your question might be answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082195/does-the-loader-modify-relocation-information-on-program-startup

Comment: Linux uses [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) so the absolute address is not known at link time.  So how could it possibly work without a relocation?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge ctor function that initializes the data PC relative. Which is basically what relocation does.